# lightning:input hides input on focus - how can I fix it?

Tags: lightninginput

On displaying a lightning:input component, everything looks fine:
[image: Displaying a value on a very nice way]

But if I click on the component, not everything looks fine:
[image: Focusing that input field...]

How can I move those up and down chevrons to the right?

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: wouldn't you just make the input wider?

Comment: Maybe this happens because the lightning component is embedded in a visualforce page... I'll give a minimal example soon.